# SQL with specific LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next example table:

```
id | user_id | data
-------------------
1  | 1       | 10
2  | 2       | 10
3  | 2       | 10
4  | 1       | 10
5  | 3       | 10
6  | 4       | 10
7  | 4       | 10
8  | 5       | 10
9  | 5       | 10
10 | 2       | 10
11 | 6       | 10
12 | 3       | 10
13 | 1       | 10
```

I need to create a SELECT query, that LIMITS my data. For example, I have a limit range (1, 3) (page number = 1, row count = 3). It should selects rows with first 3 unique `user_id`. And if there are some rows in the end of table with this first `user_id`'s, they should be included to the result. LIMIT statement is bad for this query, because I can get more than 3 rows. Output for my limit should be:

```
id | user_id | data
-------------------
1  | 1       | 10
2  | 2       | 10
3  | 2       | 10
4  | 1       | 10
5  | 3       | 10
10 | 2       | 10
12 | 3       | 10
13 | 1       | 10
```

Can you help me to generate this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
    WHERE user_id IN 
    (SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM table order by user_id LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is right. BUT. MySQL version 5.0.5: 1 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html) they are all supported. Without at least having 'IN', I can't think of a way of doing this..

Comment: @garvey: right. Too bad. Can't you update for more recent version ? 5.0 is a little bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id BETWEEN (number) AND (number+row count)
```

I know it isn't working but you should be able to make it work ^^

Comment: This will not work if the user_id is not in sequence. For example, if the table contains user_id 1,2,4 and user_id 3 is missing then this query will return less number of rows. Question mentions that the result should contain rows with first 3 unique user_id.

Comment: It states the first 3 unique user_id. So i assumed the first 3 unique user_id's after number(1).

Comment: In the OP's example the first 3 IDs are 1, 2, 3, but in some other case they could could be 2, 5, 7 (because 1, 3, 4, 6 were deleted for some reason). Your solution wouldn't work then.

Comment: Indeed but it gave me the impression that it was about a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code below can be used for Oracle & Mysql. (use `TOP` for SQL Server & Sybase)

You get all the results from your table (`t1`) that match the top 3 `user_id` (`t2`) (check the MySQL manual for the limit function)

```
SELECT *
FROM exampletable t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM exampletable
ORDER BY user_id

LIMIT 0,3 -- this is the important part

) AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
ORDER BY id
```

For the next 3 id's change the `limit 0,3` to `limit 3,6`.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not supported by Oracle -- MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL support `LIMIT`.   `TOP` is SQL Server 2000+ only.